# Add following people's links

Tags: delicious, if-this-then-that, pocket

Is it possible to create a rule with if-this-then-that for a user that I follow with Delicious so I can add his links to my Pocket?

The user isn't mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, here's what I did, maybe there's a better way.

With IFTTT, create a `this` rule for a RSS feed and add this feed from Delicious:

```
http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/rss/{user}
```

Then, `that` rule may be whatever you like, mine was Pocket.